# Best MVVM handling for functions that require context or activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

So I have a fragment and a viewModel and I'm trying to keep it clean as much as possible.
What is the best way to handle functions that require context and coroutine like data store? Or should it stay in the fragment class?

```
class LanguageFragment: Fragment() {
  private val viewModel: LanguageViewModel by viewModels()
  private val userDataStore = UserDataStore

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    subscribeForUI()
  }

  fun subscribeUI(){
     viewModel.actionRequest.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { action ->
        when (action) {            
        LanguageViewModel.LanguageActions.Save ->{

                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    userDataStore.saveStringData(
                        requireContext(),
                        DataStoreKeys.SELECTED_LANGUAGE,
                        selectedLanguage
                    )
                    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).setLanguage(selectedLanguage)
                    recreate(requireActivity())
                }

        }
    }
 }
```

ViewModel:

```
class LanguageViewModel: ViewModel() {
  private val _actionRequest = SingleLiveEvent<LanguageActions>()
  val actionRequest: LiveData<LanguageActions> = _actionRequest

  fun saveAction() = _actionRequest.setValue(LanguageActions.Save)

  sealed class LanguageActions{
     object Save: LanguageActions()
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is `LanguageActions.Save ->{`? This isn't valid syntax so I can't tell what you're actually trying to do. Anyway, if this is MVVM, this function should be in a ViewModel, not the Fragment. Same with your `setLanguage` function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i added the missing snippets. Please take a look now.

Comment: SingleLiveEvent is considered a hack and I would avoid it. You can use a SharedFlow with replay of 0 to do the same thing in a more natural way. But you don't need `actionRequest` in the first place because it should be up to the ViewModel to take requests and respond to them. You're having the ViewModel take requests, publish the requests, then having a View observe the request and perform the action. Very convoluted, and anyway a View in MVVM should never be performing data manipulation and repository interactions.

Comment: And the reason you *require* a context for saving some data is what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever find a situation where you need a context inside viewModel (situations like this needs to be avoided as much as possible), use AndroidViewModel.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel

You'll have `Application` reference, where you can get context.